# Time-filtered elements not working reliably for my app in Heroku-deployed version

Tags: heroku, time

I have an app that I helped make as part of an engineering project, deployed at https://blueplate-mks.herokuapp.com. The app shows made-up restaurant deals that a restaurant owner would use to advertise, and they display based on time-based filtering. My issue is that when I run the app through my localhost, deals that will expire later today will render under deals for "Today" until the minute they expire. But on Heroku, running on the exact same code and relying on the same database, deals that don't expire for another five (or more) hours will no longer render. The only thing I can think of is that Heroku's timezone setting doesn't match my own (Central Time), but I can't find any way to change it even after searching Heroku's support section. I can't find similar issues on Stack Overflow either so I hope someone will recognize the underlying issue and give me a clue as to what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! First of all there are blog posts saying to switch the time zone of your deployed app by using the Heroku Toolbelt to alter the default UTC time zone by entering a command like `heroku config:add TZ="America/Los_Angeles"`, where "America/Los_Angeles" refers to a [tz database time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). However, for those of us deploying by connecting our app to a Git repo, there is no way to type that command. [This Heroku support page](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) has a more up-to-date set of instructions, but it's worth adding that if you set the TZ config var in your App's settings in your Heroku dashboard from your browser, you will not want to use quotation marks around the VALUE of the variable. You may also need to manually deploy right after to see the change immediately.